# How to decode the NodeJs HTTPS request, which is returning an encoded blob?

Tags: javascript, json, encoding

I made a POST request to a server and got this back:

```
toJSON: [Function: responseToJSON],
caseless:
Caseless {
     dict:
      { server: 'Apache-Coyote/1.1',
        pragma: 'no-cache',
        'cache-control': 'no-store',
        'content-encoding': 'gzip',
        'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        'content-length': '287',
        date: 'Fri, 23 Jun 2017 14:06:47 GMT',
        connection: 'close' } },
 read: [Function],
  body: '\u001f?\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000???j\u0003!\u0014???
?C\u0018??\u0017\u001cG\u001d?k???????L\u0018\r$-}??t?]?v???|???z??4H?9\u000fe:?
??6?X\u0013Zv`?cP\u001c\u0005X?\u0011?\f\u001amKd?m?\u001f?C\u0019????;!-?o?4s\u
001eR???\u0010_t?X????B?\u0018\u001ch?\u001eTo%?3\u0016?tJ?\u000e^j?\u0014f?\u00
1e\u0013??\u0017R?\u0003?+???*{\u0017A???l\u000fd\b??,\u001b\u0015~Hx|??T?SU?\n
?\b?\u0012?k\u0019??+???sA*C\n5??\u0010V?\u001a??c?sY\u001ec$?AH\u000b2?\u0001??
\u0005??\u0015D?\u001db\'HZ??&_cL???$?~W?⌂?>??p????????\u0003z$B??\u0001\u0000\u
0000' }
```

Now I know whatever is in the encoded "body" is what I am looking for, because when I do this post request on Fiddler, It follows the same format, except the body is JSON code. Is there a way to decode this?

Edit:

```
        var options = {
            url: someURL,
            host: "SomeApi.com",
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, text/xml, application/xml',
                'User-Agent': 'RestSharp/105.2.3.0',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                'Content-Length': '0'
            },
        }
        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            console.log(response)
        })
```

Comment: `'content-encoding': 'gzip',` - its been compressed by the server & presumably is not being decompressed. The binary gzip data is getting badly mangled when interpreted as json.  How are you issuing the request and is it setup to automatically decompress?

Comment: Alright I updated it

Comment: I managed to do JSON.stringify(body) instead, and I got just the body, which is some improvement. But it is still mangled up